# I cannot initialize that shared_ptr of class C

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

```
class B;
class C;

class B
{
  public:
    B() { cout<<"B created"<<endl; }
    ~B() { cout<<"B destroyed"<<endl; }

    shared_ptr<C*> ptrc;
};

class C
{
  public:
    C() { cout<<"C created"<<endl; }
    ~C() { cout<<"C destroyed"<<endl; }
};

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<B*> bb = make_shared<B*>(new B);
    bb->ptrc = make_shared<C*>(new C);// this line gives error
}
```

```
error:
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:133:9: error: request for member ‘ptrc’ in ‘*((std::__shared_ptr_access<B*, __gnu_cxx::_S_atomic, false, false>*)(& bb))->std::__shared_ptr_access<B*, __gnu_cxx::_S_atomic, false, false>::operator->()’, which is of pointer type ‘std::__shared_ptr_access<B*, __gnu_cxx::_S_atomic, false, false>::element_type’ {aka ‘B*’} (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
      133 |     bb->ptrc = make_shared<C*>(new C);
```

I have created 2 classes B and C. In B, there is a shared_ptr to C. In main I create a shared_ptr of B. From the object of B , i.e, bb, I can not initialize that shared_ptr of C.

Comment: Why do you have a `shared_ptr<C*>`? What feature in your application wouldn't work with a normal `shared_ptr<C>`?

Comment: Off topic but... what is the purpose of having a `std::shared_ptr` to a pointer type (e.g. `std::shared_ptr<B *>` rather than `std::shared_ptr<B>`)?  Why the extra level of indirection?

Answer (score 4):

`bb` is a `shared_ptr` to pointer `B*`, i.e. nearly a pointer to pointer. You can dereference it like

```
(*bb)->ptrc = make_shared<C*>(new C);
```

But, your code has memory leak, objects created by `new` are not `delete`ed. The primary purpose of using smart pointers is lost here. Just don't use `shared_ptr` to pointer, but to the class like `B` and `C` directly, e.g.

```
shared_ptr<B> bb = make_shared<B>(); // bb is a shared_ptr to B
bb->ptrc = make_shared<C>(); // declare ptrc as shared_ptr<C> too
```

Answer (score 0):

`shared_ptr` are ment to deal with objects, not pointers - so there's no need to declare `shared_ptr<B*>` and `shared_ptr<C*>`: you can use `shared_ptr<B>` and `shared_ptr<C>`. This means that the initialization code should be:

```
int main()
{
    shared_ptr<B> bb = make_shared<B*>();
    bb->ptrc = make_shared<C>();// this line gives error
}
```

This yields the expected output:

```
B created
C created
B destroyed
C destroyed
```